# Is it possible to output a drop-down list with values from DB in an easier way?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

This way is not greatest. I'm looking for a better way. Is it possible to do without Lists?

My PageController:

```
public class CreateUserPageController {

@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;


@RequestMapping(value = "/create-user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("admin/create-user");
    model.addObject("user", new User());
    UserRoleDTO[] roles = UserRoleDTO.values();
    List<String> roleNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (UserRoleDTO role : roles) {
        roleNames.add(role.getName());
    }
    model.addObject("roleNames", roleNames);
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userServiceImpl.create(user);
    return showForm();
    }
}
```

My JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Create test</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create Test</h1>
<form:form method="POST" action="/create-test" modelAttribute="topicTestDTO">
    <form:input path="topic.name" type="text" list="topic_list" placeholder="choose or create topic"/>
    <datalist id="topic_list">
        <c:forEach items="${topicList}" var="topic">
            <option>${topic}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    <form:input path="test.name" type="text" placeholder="create test name"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help. 
If you need more information, tell me which one and I'll complete the code.

Comment: Please tell what kind of improvement do you want , what is your purpose to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is for every request it goes to Database to retrieve the data, even data is not changing also it reduces the performance of application.

By using local cache we can achieve performance, so while application loading it self data will be queried from database and store it in cache,then we can reuse the data from cache.